# making animation with kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I wanted to make a kivy program that lets an rectangle run over the window that stops, when it reachs the left end of the window.
I tried to solve this with the clock schedule, but it did not work.
Here is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.animation import Animation

from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    enemy:
        pos: 100, 300
<enemy>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 10, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
''')
class Root(Widget):
    pass

class enemy(Widget):
    velocity = ListProperty([1, 0])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ClockRect, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/60.)

    def Update(self, *args):
        self.y -= self.velocity[0]
        if self.y < 1:
            self.velocity[0] = 0

class app(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app().run()
```

I get an error in line 14:

```
 pos: 100, 300
    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

why is this syntax invalid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enemy` is treated as a property, and `pos: 100, 300` is not valid Python to be assigned to a property. Your widget class names must start with an uppercase letter - otherwise the parser has no way to distinguish between widgets and properties.

This will work:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    Enemy:
        pos: 100, 300
<Enemy>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 10, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
''')

...

class Enemy(Widget):
    ...
```